# ClickOnce Deployment Issue

Tags: .net, windows, clickonce

I find myself in a very strange situation.

In the past I've worked a lot with ClickOnce deployments and I know they can be error prone, but this last one is quite strange: **some** users get the following error if they try to start the application using the ClickOnce link (), **but** if they locate the EXE under the Apps\2.0 folder and click directly on it the application starts just fine.

Other users can start the application just fine, without any issues.

---

```
ERROR:Event 1026, .NET Runtime:
 
Application: MyApplication.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(System.Configuration.ExceptionAction)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(System.Configuration.XmlUtil, System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Configuration.OverrideModeSetting, Boolean)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(System.Configuration.XmlUtil, System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Configuration.OverrideModeSetting, Boolean)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(System.Configuration.XmlUtil)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
 
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)
 
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
   at Selerant.DevEx.Locale..cctor()
 
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
   at Selerant.DevEx.Locale.GetString(System.String, System.String)
   at Selerant.MyApplication.ClientMessageBox.ShowError(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, System.String, System.String, System.String)
   at Selerant.MyApplication.MainForm.Main(System.String[])
 
ERROR: Event 1000, Application Error:
 
Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, version: 3.4.0.2287, time stamp: 0x60c9160e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1151, time stamp: 0x891df6d3
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000034ed9
Faulting process id: 0x3ee0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d794338c62901f
Faulting application path: C:\Users\pdefilippo\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\333D8D7P.YZ5\CLR3A83B.AON\deve..tion_7d3a9c4a810e8b8c_0003.0004_5e84283d0fbe2e5d\MyApplication.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 32778313-81d5-472c-b583-5fa354384538
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
INFORMATION: Event 1001, Windows Error Reporting:
 
Fault bucket 1688808424877071863, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
 
Problem signature:
P1: MyApplication.exe
P2: 3.4.0.2287
P3: 60c9160e
P4: System.Xml
P5: 4.8.4084.0
P6: 5dda3e2e
P7: b85
P8: 27
P9: System.TypeInitialization
P10:
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not about code, it is about knowledge of ClickOnce as there is actually no code on my side that leads to this exception.